# Convergence of $a_{n+1}=x+\sin a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume $x \in \Bbb R$ is a real number, consider the following sequence:

$a_{n+1}=x+\sin a_{n}, a_0=0.$

For which $x$, the sequence above is convergent $?$ If $x \in \pi \Bbb Z$ then it's obvious, but I wonder what will happen for other $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(t)=x+\sin(t)$ and $a=f(a)$. According to fixed point theorems, your sequence converges if

$$|f'(a)|<1$$

Which trivially holds if

$$a\notin\pi\Bbb Z$$

But if $a\in\pi\Bbb Z$, well, as you say, the convergence is obvious.

Thus, it converges for any $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you write the details?

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang What details? I've pretty much included everything?

Comment: According to what fixed point theorem ?  And what is $a$?

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang $a$ is the unique number such that $a=f(a)$, and we wish to show $a=\lim a_n$.

Comment: As per the theorem, it is on Wikipedia for fixed points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attractive_fixed_points

Comment: This theorem may not be applied here as how do you know whether $t$ is sufficient closely to $a$? The attractiveness property is not a global property.

Comment: As Wikipedia says: However, if the function $f$ is continuously differentiable in an open neighbourhood of a fixed point $x_0$, and $|f'(x_0)|<1$, attraction is guaranteed. Either extend this neighborhood so that it is large enough or note that $x-1<f(t)<x+1$. This means that $x-1<f(a)=a<x+1$, and so by $a_1$, you should be close enough to $a$ to guarantee the convergence.

Comment: This works for some $t$. In fact if you read the proof of this property, you will find that the open neighborhood is choose such that $sup|f^'|=p<1$ in this neighborhood as $|f^'(x_0)|<1$ hence $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq p|x-y|$ and we can apply the Banach fixed point theorem. But if $(x-1,x+1)$ contains $k\pi$, this method fails.

Comment: Mmm, I see. Probably also explains the slow convergence rate if $x$ is close to $k\pi$.

Comment: Hm, I think this can be done by noting that $f(x)$ is either convex or concave near $a$ and applying an argument based on secants.